# Using docker with RDS (Prod), but confused about local DB setup (dev)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, amazon-web-services, docker, rds

I'm designing a Rails webapp using Docker and for a variety of reasons, I'd like to use RDS in the Production environment for its configurability & durability purposes, rather than a Docker container-based DB (this is a requirement).

I realize that I can configure **database.yml** to point to my RDS instance for Prod env, and to some local DB instance in my local dev env.

However, I'm confused as to whether to use a container-based DB in my local dev environment, or an external one like MySQL Server.

Based on the Docker pattern of env-agnostic containers, I suppose that having a container-based DB in only some envs wouldn't make any sense (in fact, I don't think `docker-compose.yml` would even support something like this), so I am assuming I'll need to go with the MySQL Server solution for my local dev env.

Has anybody else been through such a requirement? Let me know if I am thinking about this the right way. Also, would this pose any potential issues for DB migration scripts?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Great questions Donald.

I have a postgres container set up for use locally using my `dev.docker-compose.yml` file.

And on prod, like you do, I have my `database.yml` configuration pointing to my RDS database.

On my prod docker compose file, I do not have any database container specified since I am using RDS

```
# prod.docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      target: prod
      args:
        PG_MAJOR: '13'
        RUBY_VERSION: '2.6.6'
        BUNDLER_VERSION: '2.1.4'
    env_file: .env
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: ./bin/start_dev_server
    image: ${REGISTRY_HOST}
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

# dev.docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      target: dev
      args:
        PG_MAJOR: '13'
        RUBY_VERSION: '2.6.6'
        BUNDLER_VERSION: '2.1.4'
    env_file: .env
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    command: ./bin/start_dev_server
    volumes:
      - ".:/sokoplace"¬
      - bundle:/bundle
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  postgres:
    image: "postgres:13-alpine"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust

volumes:
  bundle:
  postgres:

# config/database.yml
production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['PRODUCTION_POSTGRES_HOST'] %>
```