# Undefined volume when deploying docker container to ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I'm following [this guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/ecs-integration/) and currently trying to run my compose app using `docker ecs compose up` but I'm getting this error:

```sh
% docker ecs compose up
service "feature-test-web" refers to undefined volume : invalid compose project
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

x-web:
  &web
  build: ./web
  volumes:
    - ./web:/app
    - /app/node_modules

x-api:
  &api
  build: ./api
  volumes:
    - ./api:/app
  env_file:
    - ./api/.env
  depends_on:
    - postgres
    - redis
  links:
    - mailcatcher

services:
  web:
    << : *web
    environment:
      - API_HOST=http://localhost:3000
    ports:
      - "1234:1234"
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    << : *api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=portal
      - POSTGRES_PASS=portal
    ports:
      - 8000:5432
    restart: on-failure
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.4-alpine
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  sidekiq:
    build: ./api
    env_file:
      - ./api/.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis


  mailcatcher:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - '1080:1080'

  feature-test-api:
    << : *api
    depends_on:
      - selenium
      - feature-test-web

  feature-test-web:
    << : *web
    environment:
      - API_HOST=http://feature-test-api:3210

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.141.59-neon
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - 5901:5900
```

What am I missing? Running `docker compose up` by itself works and I'm able to go to `localhost:1234` to see the app running. I'm trying to deploy this to AWS but it's been very difficult to do so if I'm doing this wrong, any pointers to the right way would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: You have some `volumes:` that overwrite your image's `/app` directory.  Does deleting these help?  The ECS cluster won't have a local copy of your code (it's supposed to be built into the image) so those mounts won't work.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your response. If it's not too much, could you point out which lines I should delete? I'm not sure I understand your comment too well. Thanks!

Comment: Delete the entire `volumes:` blocks under `x-web` and `x-api`.

Comment: @DavidMaze After deleting those `volumes:` blocks I'm getting a bunch of these errors instead: `service feature-test-api doesn't define a Docker image to run: incompatible attribute`. Do you know how to get over these?

Comment: @Ccyan did you solve this?

Comment: @AmeenRashad, you can look at the answer below if it can help

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the comments section, the volume mounts won't work on ECS as the cluster won't have a local copy of your code.

So as a first step, remove the entire volumes section.

Second, you'll need to first build a docker image out of your code, and push it to a docker registry of your liking, then link to it on your docker compose as follows

```
x-api:
  &api
  image: 12345.abcd.your-region.amazonaws.com/your-docker-repository
  env_file:
    - ./api/.env
  depends_on:
    - postgres
    - redis
```

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335543/using-docker-with-rds-prod-but-confused-about-local-db-setup-dev/65364648#65364648) could give you more insight into how I deploy to ECS.